# The Lebesgue Measure of a subset that contains no intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, interval-arithmetic

I have taken out a book to help me understand measure theory better, one of the examples (that one has to do alone) asks:

'Show there is a closed subset of [0,1] that contains no interval but it's Lebesgue measure exceeds 0.999'

I've had a good look at questions similar to this one and have got some general ideas of how to solve this problem however I'm very unsure how to go about it:
Let us call our subset A, if λ(A)>0.999 with λ being the Lebesgue measure then we would have to consider [0,1] as the union of intervals [0,0.001]⋃[0.001,0.002]⋃...⋃[0.999,1] and deduce A from here however we've already said that A is closed so using rationals wouldn't work as [0,1]∩Q isn't closed in R, maybe that means constructing R\Q however the example has already stated A contains no intervals.

I'm very confused, how do I go about finding this result?

Comment: I think the set off irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ will do the job. Also look for fat Cantor sets. For any $0\leq \alpha<1$ one can construct a fat Cantor set of measure $\alpha$; these sets are nowhere dense (have no interior).

Comment: @OliverDíaz ... Irrationals would answer it except for that pesky word "closed" in there.

Comment: A hint is: start with $[0,1]$, then subtract a sequence $V_n$ of open intervals of total length less than $0.001$, say one interval surrounding each rational.

Comment: @wizardofloz: On account of GEdgar's observation to my original comment, I retract the set of irrationals from the list. Fat Cantor sets will do.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you foy your help, I'm unsure as to how I'd model such a sequence, one interval surrounding each rational however total length less than 1 say $V_n$=($\frac{1}{10000}$,$\frac{1}{1000}$)={(a$_n$,b$_n$): n∃Z$_{10}$, a$_n$=$\frac{n}{10000}$, b$_n$=$\frac{n+1}{10000}$} would suffice, hence the complement of [0,1]\V$_{n}$=[1/10000,1/1000]∩R=[1/10000,1/1000] is open hence giving us a closed subset of measure greater than 0.999, but surely this still contains intervals?